# Installing Behat via Pear on Mac Os X Problems

Tags: macos, behat

I am using the follwoing turotiral to install behat and mink on my mountain lion macbook.

http://www.ifusio.com/blog/how-to-install-behat-mink-on-mac-osx

It all seems to go fine until you run the behat command , then I get the following error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\ProgressHelper' not found in /Users/waseem/pear/share/pear/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php on line 966
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /Users/waseem/pear/bin/behat:0
PHP   2. Behat\Behat\Console\BehatApplication->__construct() /Users/waseem/pear/bin/behat:26
PHP   3. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->__construct() /Users/waseem/pear/share/pear/behat/src/Behat/Behat/Console/BehatApplication.php:32
PHP   4. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->getDefaultHelperSet() /Users/waseem/pear/share/pear/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:75

Fatal error: Class 'Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\ProgressHelper' not found in /Users/waseem/pear/share/pear/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php on line 966

Call Stack:
    0.0002     632656   1. {main}() /Users/waseem/pear/bin/behat:0
    0.0036    1350424   2. Behat\Behat\Console\BehatApplication->__construct() /Users/waseem/pear/bin/behat:26
    0.0036    1350504   3. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->__construct() /Users/waseem/pear/share/pear/behat/src/Behat/Behat/Console/BehatApplication.php:32
    0.0036    1350816   4. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->getDefaultHelperSet() /Users/waseem/pear/share/pear/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:75
```

If i install it via the Github method it all seems fine , this is just bugging me why this happens . I don't have Symfony on the machine.

Maybe because I installed --alldeps ? I have tried uninstalling and trying again and same issue

Answer (score 0):

[Behat PEAR channel](http://pear.behat.org/) is not maintained anymore. Latest Behat versions (>=2.4) are not available there.

The best and easiest way to install Behat is to use composer. I'd recommend to follow [the original docs](http://docs.behat.org/quick_intro.html#installation). Pear method is not listed there anymore.

Comment: This still happens when using Composer also.

Comment: If you have behat installed globally, as well as Symfony in your shared folder, you must specify the local behat executable in your project folder. So from the quick start docs, in `ls_project`, it's `../bin/behat --init`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for that , however the only method i got to work for me on Mac OS X reliably and I tried on both snow lepoard and Mountain lion was using the .phar method of installing.

The composer method although it seems simpler kept producing errors when following the guide found at

http://docs.behat.org/cookbook/behat_and_mink.html

The error i got is below so I stuck to using the phar files.

```
  [Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\InvalidArgumentException]                                                       
  Unable to parse file "/Users/waseem/Behat/vendor/behat/mink-extension/src/Behat/MinkExtension/services/sessions/selenium2.xml".  






  [InvalidArgumentException]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
  [ERROR 1840] Element '{http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services}parameter', attribute 'type': [facet 'enumeration'] The value 'integer' is not an element of the set {'collection', 'service', 'string', 'constant'}. (in /Users/waseem/Behat/ - line 20, column 0)  
  [ERROR 1824] Element '{http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services}parameter', attribute 'type': 'integer' is not a valid value of the atomic type '{http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services}parameter_type'. (in /Users/waseem/Behat/ - line 20, column 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at behat\autoload_map.php.  This file substitutes for the Symfony autoloader when that file is not found.  It contains an array that maps namespace\class to directory and file.  With a few additions, you can get this version of Behat working.

If it is true, as others have stated, that the PEAR channel is no longer supported for Behat, you are on your own with this solution.  Personally, I'll be looking into another method to keep my Behat installation up to date.